# Build runner package in my flutter app for JSON serialization, No \.dart_tool\flutter_gen\pubspec.yaml` found

Tags: flutter-dependencies, build-runner

After i run this command:

```
dart run build_runner build
```

I have below log in terminal:

```
Bad state: Unable to generate package graph, no `D:\android\<YOUR_APP_NAME>\.dart_tool\flutter_gen\pubspec.yaml` found.
#0      _pubspecForPath (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:253:5)
#1      _parsePackageDependencies (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:227:21)
#2      PackageGraph.forPath (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:105:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      main (file:///C:/Users/001/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.4.6/bin/build_runner.dart:27:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

My flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  
Framework • revision 9cd3d0d9ff (3 months ago) • 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
Engine • revision 90fa3ae28f                                              
Tools • Dart 3.0.2 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

After some try i got this solution in [Build runner issues](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2835), But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete this path in your project:

```
D:\android\<NAME_YOUR_APP>\.dart_tool\
```

After run this command:

```
dart run build_runner build
```

Build runner ask you choose some action, Choose 1 option to delete and generate new one.

Comment: When I delete that folder, then run the command, no questions are asked, the folder reappears and so does the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen) package to your dev_dependencies in pubspec.yaml:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  
  flutter_gen: ^version
```